# How do you adjust the value of a variable based on user input?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a quick number guessing script in C with 5 chances to guess a number correctly. If the number is guessed correctly, I want the computer to skip to the end and finish running the script instead of continuing to run until all 5 tries are used up. I'm brand new to coding, trying to learn through practice + forums, and don't know a lot of vocabulary or C syntax so explanations in simple terms would be very much appreciated.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
     int Chance, x;
     printf("Guess the Number in 5 Tries! (0-30)");
     for (Chance=0; Chance<5; Chance++)
      {
          scanf("%d",&x);
          if (x==20)
            printf("Correct!"); //Change Chance to 5 upon answer
          else if (x<20)
              printf("Not quite... \n");
          else
              printf("Too much... \n");
      }
    printf("Try Again!");
    return 0;
    }
```

I've tried putting Chance=5 after printf("Correct!") and received this error:

```
    main.c: In function ‘main’:
    main.c:21:7: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
       21 |       else if (x<20)
          |       ^~~~
```

That was really my only idea for how to do this, very much appreciate any advice given.

Comment: You need to put a block after the `if`. Like the following `if (x == 20) { printf(...); Chance = 5; }`

Comment: You can only omit the braces if the body of the `if` is a single statement. If you want multiple statements, you need braces. Just get in the habit of always using braces and you'll never have a problem.

Comment: Please show the *failing* code. The code you show builds fine.